# AppBarLayout and SearchBar exception in Android Studio Design (MDC 1.8.0-rc01)

Tags: android, android-studio, material-components-android

I added a **AppBarLayout** and this exception occurred in the Design tab of the IDE.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Motion easing theme attribute must be an @interpolator resource for ?attr/motionEasing*Interpolator attributes or a string for ?attr/motionEasing* attributes.
    at com.google.android.material.motion.MotionUtils.resolveThemeInterpolator(MotionUtils.java:74)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.<init>(AppBarLayout.java:277)
...
```

I'm using Android Studio Flamingo Canary 11 and MDC 1.8.0-rc01.

Using MDC 1.7.0 fixes the layout rendering problem, but I need the 1.8.0 because I want to use the new SearchBar (that is not rendered aswell). Is there a trick that makes all work or I ust have to wait the bug fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Version 1.8.0-rc01 also has other bug(s). In my opinion, use version 1.7.0 until the bug is fixed in the future.

Comment: Thanks, it is what I'm actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the attribute with latest

> [Easing](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Motion.md#easing)

Comment: How can I do that? Thanks.